# How to get this equation from the variance formula？

Tags: variance

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be an iid (independent and identically distributed) sample with mean $ \mu $ and variance $\sigma^2$.

How to show $$ (n-1)S^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (Xi-\overline X)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (Xi-\mu ) ^2 - n(\mu-\overline X) ^2                                $$

I found that if I treat  $\mu$ equals $\overline X$ , it would do. But I don't think that's right.

Comment: Expand $X_i-\overline X=X_i-\mu+\mu-\overline X$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have to expand the first X_i-$\overline X $as X_i-$\mu $+$\mu $-$\overline X$ and the second X_i-$\overline X$ as  X_i-$\mu$-$\mu$+$\overline X $to get there.

Comment: What ? What do you mean by *first* and *second* ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  (X_i-$\overline X$)^2 has two X_i-$\overline X$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_i:=X_i-\mu$. We have $\overline Y=\overline X-\mu$.

Then

$$\sum_i(Y_i-\overline Y)^2=\sum_iY_i^2-2\overline Y\sum_i Y+n\overline Y^2=\sum_iY_i^2-n\overline Y^2.$$